# Swift - Create a menu to navigate to the same view controller from multiple places

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

This is my code to navigate different navigation controllers in my app.

I have a modal view to present the menu and later select where navigate,
this is a good approach?

```
func circleMenu(_: CircleMenu, buttonDidSelected _: UIButton, atIndex: Int) {

weak var pvc = self.presentingViewController

    if atIndex == 1 {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Experiencia", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExperienciaNavigationController")
            pvc?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    if atIndex == 2 {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Servicios", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ServiciosNavigationController")
            pvc?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    if atIndex == 3 {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Book", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DemoViewController")
            pvc?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

And later in other vc that was selected I have this code to return to root

```
func back() {
   self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And the final question its about the navigation controller that will be closed... Will be closed all the views presented? to avoid memory issues.

*I read about implement a coordinator pattern. but I don't know if this case to do that* [Coordinator pattern or  Navigator](http://medium.com/@johnsundell/navigation-in-swift-e4ed18031653)

Comment: Looks good to me.
Second question: Yes should be fine, as long as you don't keep a strong reference to vc, which you are NOT doing in this code.  All good.

Comment: ok thanks! I read about implement a coordinator pattern. but I don't know if this case to do that https://medium.com/@johnsundell/navigation-in-swift-e4ed18031653